# Is there enough information in this diagram to calculate the length of segment OA?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am in the microscopy field and am trying to estimate the distance a feature might move due to thermal expansion. The diagram below is a simplification of the mounting scheme for the measurement. The units are in microns.

I have a feature at point O. During heating, my hypothesis is the (silicon) mount expands from point D to point O and from point E to point O, pushing the feature from point O to point A. The diagram shows rays EO and DO have different length, but this is simply because I snipped part of ray EO; assume ray EO and DO are the same length. The length 4 is the length calculated from linear expansion of silicon. Since the feature at point O experiences expansion from opposing directions, the feature may be pushed out toward point A.

I am interested in comparing an estimate of length OA to the measurement. If my hypotheses is correct, the length OA should be around 15. I have tried to leverage the fact that $\Delta ABC$ is similar to $\Delta AOD$, and apply $\frac{AB}{AO}$=$\frac{BC}{OD}$=$\frac{AC}{AD}$, but this is tough since I have no side lengths of $\Delta ABC$. Perhaps there is a way to get these side lengths that I'm not seeing? Or a way to leverage the limited number of angles given? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Start with any segment $OA$ and try to complete it to a picture like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't have enough hints for me. If you could provide more hints, or a solution, that would be helpful.

Comment: There is not enough information. Try to slide point $A$ along the ray $BA$.

Comment: There's definitely not enough information. As no piece of the information given has included any mentions of point $C$ (they're getting lonely over here), I'd assume that this problem is missing context involving point $C$ (such as the length of $AC$, the measurement of $\angle{BCD}$,...).